# Facebook graph api image sources not matching size given in response

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I need to get the largest image Facebook has saved.  According to the docs the image returned in the 'source' field should be a maximum of 960px wide now.  Which I can confirm.  But if you look at the 'images' field there are loads of other urls at apparently different, and larger sizes.  However when I actually follow the urls the images aren't the size reported at all!  They are never larger than 960.  See this example:  http://graph.facebook.com/10150369820292147?fields=images.  Can we not get access to larger than 960?  I thought they were saving larger images now as they have a full screen option in the gallery.
Thanks

Comment: Just a blind guess but perhaps they were only saving older images with this max width but storing the meta-data about the original file size, have you tried with newly uploaded images, how about using a web debugging proxy like firebug or charles to see if when you browse a fullscreen image on facebook that it is in fact a larger amount of pixels in the image.

Comment: I'm not sure what would be the point in them supplying the images field with several urls and sizes if they are all to the same size image?  Looking at facebook now though I can't find their fullscreen feature anymore to check the sizes.

Answer (score 4):

The width and height fields of the first entry in the `images` array indicate how large the image should be for display inside of a 2048 x 2048 box, but the actual image file is still limited to 960 x 960 pixels.

Comment: That assestment comes from experience or is there any doc the OP can check for future reference?

Comment: This is just from experience. I tried to track down a doc that states this, but was unable to fine one.